# Ruby Find a value in a complex JSON object

Tags: ruby

I need to find the value of a particular key (say "key") in a JSON object. Since I am getting the JSON object dynamically, I do not know the structure of the JSON object.

Could anyone tel me an easy way to find the value of a key in such a JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know the structure of the JSON then you will need to do more work to inspect all possible keys.

You might just have to do a recursive descent and iterate over all keys until you find the key whose name matches `key` and then grab its value.

Comment: Ya, I thought of doing that. But I just wanted to know if there was any easier way that I didn't know of.

Comment: @rlecaro2 - wut? `hasOwnProperty` is Javascript but the poster said he is using Ruby